# What is cross validation doing in my spatial ecology model, and how necessary is it to run?

Tags: cross-validation, kernel-smoothing, ecology

I'm currently using the R `latticeDensity` package to estimate home ranges of animals.

Within the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/latticeDensity/vignettes/latticeDensity.html),

> The minimum uvc (Unbiased CrossValidation criterion of Sain, Baggerly and Scott (1994)) was at 150 steps. I’ll use that many steps to get a final, smooth density estimate using createDensity.
>   [image: minimum uvc output graph]

I've tried reading the cited Sain, Baggerly and Scott (1994) paper, but unfortunately it is above and beyond my understanding. Similarly, any searches for "cross validating" a model seem are largely applicable to people who know what they're doing with custom built models (e.g., [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/why-and-how-to-cross-validate-a-model-d6424b45261f) or [here](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/crossvalidation/)).

From my very basic understanding (largely from [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/290919/what-is-cross-validation-for)), cross validation ensures you do not overfit your model. In order to not overfit this home range density model, one must choose the *lowest* `k` value that is spit out by this UVC function.

The model inputs in this particular package are lat/long animal locations within a lattice grid, the distance between each grid point, the number of 'steps' an animal is making across that grid, and a probability value that the animal will jump to the next grid point vs. staying in place. From the original `latticeDensity` publication:

> This would be analogous to adding a quantity of dye to each location where a fish or animal was observed, then allowing the dye to diffuse outward. A density map based on the concentration of the dye at different times would result in a density estimator that is faithful to the boundaries of the region.

Unfortunately, running the cross validation function within the `latticeDensity` package takes hours to run on my computer, and is not feasible given the number of home ranges I need to calculate. I understand the underlying ecological principle of animals diffusing across a grid, but I do not actually understand what the purpose of cross validation is within the context of calculating home range size.

My questions are:

1. What is this UVC method actually *doing*?
2. How important is running my model with the lowest `k` value to produce an ecologically meaningful result? Can I just choose a `k` value and run with it for every one of my species home range models, or will this `k` value likely change drastically between species?